# Convert String to byte[] array

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, byte

I want to convert a String to a byte array but the array must have 256 positions, I mean, like this:

```
public byte[] temporal1 = new byte[256];
public byte[] temporal2 = new byte[256];
```

So, when I do:

```
String send = "SEND_MESSAGE";
String sendAck = "SEND_MESSAGE_ACK";
temporal1 = send.getBytes();
temporal2 = sendAck.getBytes();
```

I get this error: "./th.java:24: error: <identifier> expected". I know that if I do `public byte[] temporal1 = send.getBytes();`it works, but I need the array with that size to compare it with other byte array byte to byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please show the exact Exception or Error which is occurring in the console. because it works completely fine with me.

```
byte b1[] = new byte[256];
String s = "hello there";
b1 = s.getBytes();
System.out.println(b1);
```

Comment: why not btye[] b1 = new byte[256]; ?

Comment: I get this error "./th.java:24: error: expected" but it's ok ... Patrick Parker solved my problem ;)

Comment: @Omore well you can also go with `byte[] b1` there is no difference in there. But go with the `byte[] b1` as you suggested it gives a better understanding while reading the core that the declared datatype is an array, ya my bad, sorry :P

Answer (score 0):

To have the byte array `temporal1` padded upto 256 bytes, you might do:

```
public byte[] temporal1 = new byte[256];
String send = "SEND_MESSAGE";
byte[] sendB = send.getBytes(send, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.arraycopy(sendB, 0, temporal1, 0, Math.max(256, sendB.length));
```

If you want a C like terminating 0 byte, sendB may only provide 255 bytes: `Math.max(255, sendB.length)`.

Better:

```
String send = "SEND_MESSAGE";
byte[] sendB = send.getBytes(send, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
byte[] temporal1 = Arrays.copyOf(sendB, 256); // Pads or truncates.
temportal1[255] = (byte) 0; // Maybe
```

Comment: what if my source byte[] doesn't have 256 bytes(It has <256) but I want destination array to have 256 bytes.

Comment: The above pads the 256 bytes array with `(byte)0`s at the end. Those can be trimmed when receiving at the other end.

Comment: I haven't tried the second block of your code. But first block is throwing error if source doesn't have 256 bytes. And I guess adding 0's at the beginning will be helpful rather than adding at the end

Comment: `temporal1` is the 256 byte array; sendB a temporary array for conversion of the String. I can but guess on the zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

To get a `byte[]` from `String` with defined size:

```
public static byte[] toBytes(String data, int length) {
    byte[] result = new byte[length];
    System.arraycopy(data.getBytes(), 0, result, length - data.length(), data.length());
    return result;
}
```

**Ex:**
`byte[] sample = toBytes("SEND_MESSAGE", 256);`

`sample` will be of size 256.